# Issue with GIDSignIn and handleURL:

Tags: ios, google-plus

Hello I'm stuck in this method.

What I've did:

1. Carefully configured project to use Google Auth API
2. It works fine until processing of OAUth callback in this method of GIDSignIn.

I.e. everything works fine, but this method simple discard provided OAuth callback URL and returns NO.
I've checked provided URL - everything looks fine: it contains correct URL schema and OAuth data.

Comment: Not a lot to go on.  Can you post a code snippet and maybe a log of what's going on?

Comment: The handler just does not work. I'm looking for someone who was able to use it or had such problem and know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It was issue in my code.
Namely, missed parameters **sourceApplication** and **annotation** (both were set to nil).

As discovered, now those parameters are required both for Google and Facebook SDK sign-in.